# dynamic buttons

Tags: autohotkey

I am looking into the possibility of creating dynamic button names in a dynamic button list,  that would start dynamic functions. Judging by how a Gui is setup I assume this is impossible but I have seen some amazing things on here.

Example. A button would appear for every item in a file and pressing that button would run that particular item.

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop that checks for items in the file and makes or removes a hotkey that runs that item.
In my example ITEM is a path to a program you wish to run, and you can create hotkeys dynamically by using http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm.

Comment: It's slightly more complicated.  You can't dynamically create labels, so you have to get the pressed one using [A_GuiControl](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#GuiControl), which gives the variable name for a control.  You then have to make sure that using the v attribute of the control, you can deduce the command to run.  An array would be suitable; mapping control vars to commands.